# How can I fix the XML Java button break down?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-button

I have a program project. I have three buttons in the same class (mainpage.java), but one of the buttons doesn't work!

Although I have designed them (the three buttons) in the same form!

**My XML:**

```
    <Button
        android:text="Facebook videos"
        android:theme="@style/btncar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/zee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="fb"
        android:id="@+id/fbbtn"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/fbico"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="YouTube videos"
        android:theme="@style/btncar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/zee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="gotoyt"
        android:id="@+id/ytbtn"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ytico"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="others"
        android:theme="@style/btncar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/zee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/allico"
        android:onClick="gotoalllinks"
        android:id="@+id/othbtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>
```

**And my Java classes:**

```
public void gotoyt(View v) {
    ent.putExtra("linktype", "YouTube");
    startActivity(ent);
}

public void gotoalllinks(View v) {
    ent.putExtra("linktype", "other");
    startActivity(ent);
}

public void fbgo(View v) {
    ent.putExtra("linktype", "Facebook");
    startActivity(ent);
}
```

When I click on "Facebook videos" button (the first one), my program gets closed!

Comment: you don't have callback `fb(View view)` method in your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped the callback in your layout, so you need to change the `android:onClick="fb"` of your Facebook button to `android:onClick="gotoyt"`.

So, change your layout to:

```
<Button
    android:text="YouTube videos"
    android:theme="@style/btncar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/zee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="gotoyt"
    android:id="@+id/ytbtn"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ytico"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

<Button
    android:text="others"
    android:theme="@style/btncar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/zee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/allico"
    android:onClick="gotoalllinks"
    android:id="@+id/othbtn"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

<Button
    android:text="Facebook videos"
    android:theme="@style/btncar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/zee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="fbgo"
    android:id="@+id/fbbtn"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/fbico"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first button's XML content should have `android:onClick="fb"`, because your function name is `fbgo`.

Also, check if the XML content is correct, as your first button does not seem to have a `<` opening tag.